# Radio Button in Lightning Design

Tags: visualforce, lightning-design-system

I want to use radio buttons in Lightning Design. In my Visualforce page, I am retrieving the options from my controller and doing something like this:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!SiteDetails}" var="rad"> 
<apex:selectRadio value="{!rad.site__c}" rendered="{!rad.Site_Type__c == 'Radio'}">
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!SiteOptions[rad]}" />  
</apex:selectRadio>
```

Is there a way to do the same thing in Lightning Design?

Edit: I mean a Visualforce page built using the Lightning Design System.

Comment: do you mean for a vf page built using the lightning design system or a proper lightning component?

Comment: Were you able to get this working?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`lightningStylesheets`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/vf_dev_best_practices_slds_lightningstylesheets.htm) attribute for [`<apex:page>`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_page.htm) to automatically style most Visualforce components on your page (including [`<apex:selectRadio>`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_selectRadio.htm)) to match the Lightning Experience UI:

**Example:**

```
<apex:page lightningStylesheets="true">
```

Alternatively, if you want to use the [Lightning Design System (SLDS)](https://lightningdesignsystem.com/) to style your radio buttons in a [Radio Group](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/radio-group/) (in a similar format to how you have them set up in your example), you can use the following concept:

**Example:**

```
<!-- Include the Lightning Design System -->

<apex:slds />

<!-- Begin SLDS-styled content -->

<div class="slds-scope">

    <!-- Create a Radio Group -->

    <fieldset class="slds-form-element">
        <div class="slds-form-element__control">
            <apex:variable var="i" value="{!0}" />
            <apex:repeat value="{!SiteDetails}" var="rad">
                <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!rad.Site_Type__c == 'Radio'}">
                    <span class="slds-radio">
                        <input id="radio-{!i}" name="options" type="radio" value="{!rad.site__c}" />
                        <label class="slds-radio__label" for="radio-{!i}">
                            <span class="slds-radio_faux"></span>
                            <span class="slds-form-element__label">{!SiteOptions[rad]}</span>
                        </label>
                    </span>
                    <apex:variable var="i" value="{!i + 1}" />
                </apex:outputPanel>
            </apex:repeat>
        </div>
    </fieldset>

</div>
```

**Result:**

[image]